# How do i apply conditional formating that is specific for each row?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my worksheet I would like to apply some conditional formatting that alerts me if the following is true:

```
IF (len(J7) + len(h14) + len(i14) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I14.
IF (len(J7) + len(h15) + len(i15) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I15.
IF (len(J7) + len(h16) + len(i16) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I16.
IF (len(J7) + len(h18) + len(i18) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I18.
IF (len(J7) + len(h19) + len(i19) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I19.
IF (len(J7) + len(h20) + len(i20) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I20.
```

...and so on and so forth all the way down to infinity.

I'm making a string with three components, the first component is always found in J7, then it's a combination of the 'h' and 'i' cells of each row, starting from row 14 and working it's way down. If the string on that particular row is more than 256 characters, i would like a notification of some sort, for that row.

I can't get it to work using the conditional formatting tool. I select the columns i would like the formatting on, then write the formula in the Conditional Formatting tool-box and get it to work on row 14 as i would like on row 14. But when i inspect the cells on row 15, it's the same rules evaluating the cells on row 14. Basically, what I have accomplished is to apply conditional formatting on ALL of the rows that i selected if the first row meets the conditions.

Any ideas?

It doesn't have to be solved by conditional formatting.. vba or something else would work equally well..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the pattern.

```
IF (len(J7) + len(h14) + len(i14) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I14.
IF (len(J7) + len(h15) + len(i15) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I15.
IF (len(J7) + len(h16) + len(i16) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I16.
IF (len(J8) + len(h18) + len(i18) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I18.
IF (len(J9) + len(h19) + len(i19) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I19.
IF (len(J20) + len(h20) + len(i20) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I20.
```

Is this your actual pattern?

```
IF (len(J14) + len(h14) + len(i14) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I14.
IF (len(J15) + len(h15) + len(i15) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I15.
IF (len(J16) + len(h16) + len(i16) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I16.
IF (len(J18) + len(h18) + len(i18) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I18.
IF (len(J19) + len(h19) + len(i19) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I19.
IF (len(J20) + len(h20) + len(i20) > 256) = TRUE: apply some formatting on I20.
```

Comment: My mistake! Sorry, No, that wasn't what i intended. I have updated the question with a worded explanation of what i'm trying to accomplish, and corrected the pattern... Thanks for pointing out my error!

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that you need to apply the formula that applies to the **top left cell** of the range - Excel will automatically adjust the formula for the result of the range, as if the formula was being copied down the worksheet, so if you select a range like `I14:I1000` you can then apply the formula that would be correct for `I14`, i.e.

`=LEN(J$7&H14&I14)>256`

Because I used a $ in the J7 value that will "fix" the row at 7 while the other rows will increment. You don't see that explicitly but that's the way it works internally.

Note: you don't need an IF statement, just a "test" that results in `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

Select the column(s) you want to affect, and use this formula.

```
=(LEN($J$7)+LEN($H1)+LEN($I1))>256
```